# Synchronizing the app with google drive or dropbox

Tags: android

Is there any way of synchronizing the android app with google drive or dropbox or any other cloud service without having public certificate. If yes, please mention. Or is there any other procedure that can help to keep a back up of data programaticaly on cloud

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for backup you can use: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html

for synchronization, they announced a Google Drive API on the play services  [HERE](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2014/01/google-play-services-41.html), but I still can't find the documentation for it, should be available soon.

Comment: Apart from Google Drive, is there any other cloud service which can provide me such facility and that too without having public certificate

Comment: well. Drive is available now: http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/drive.html